# Display custom ribbon tab in specific outlook tabs

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am developing an Outlook AddIn with VSTO. I managed the ribbon tab and the context menu via XML and now I want to display my custom tab only when Outlook's "mail" or "contacts" tab is active.

I've already tried to solve it with the IdMso which is not a solution for me, because it will just extend the built-in tabs (so will do contextual tabs).

Further researches did not provide me with any solution or any approach.

Are there by any chance any callbacks or events that are fired when I change the Outlook tabs (e.g. from Mail to Calendar), so that I can set the visibility via code like I want to? If not, what would be another approach?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit1:**

In meanwhile I figured out how to display the custom ribbon in the explorer only:

```
public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
{
    if(ribbonID == "Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer")
        return GetResourceText("Ribbon.xml");

    return String.Empty;
}
```

**Edit2 (Solution):**

So I finally got it working, not really like the way I imagined, but the solution is acceptable.

```
public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
{
    this.ribbon = ribbonUI;
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().NavigationPane.ModuleSwitch += NavigationPane_ModuleSwitch;
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Explorers.NewExplorer += Explorers_NewExplorer;
}

private void Explorers_NewExplorer(Outlook.Explorer Explorer)
{
    Explorer.NavigationPane.ModuleSwitch += NavigationPane_ModuleSwitch;
}

private void NavigationPane_ModuleSwitch(Outlook.NavigationModule CurrentModule)
{
    ribbon.Invalidate();
}

public bool EnableButton(Office.IRibbonControl ribbonControl)
{
    Outlook.OlNavigationModuleType currentModuleType = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().NavigationPane.CurrentModule.NavigationModuleType;
    if (currentModuleType == Outlook.OlNavigationModuleType.olModuleContacts || currentModuleType == Outlook.OlNavigationModuleType.olModuleMail)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

XML for Dummy Button:

```
<button id="btnDummy" label="Click Me"        onAction="TestFunc"  size="large"  getImage="GetDummyImage"  getEnabled="EnableButton"/>
```

So every explorer has access to it's navigation pane and this pane has an event called "ModuleSwitch" (it is firing when you are switching the modules, like from contacts to Mail), and then I invalidate the ribbon. On every invalidation several functions are called like the "getEnabled" function. In the given getEnabled function I am checking, which module is currently active and return the wanted value.

Comment: Won't your tab just vanish again when you attempt to click on it ( _"...I want to display my custom tab only when Outlook's "mail" or "contacts" tab is active"_ )

Comment: No, currently it is displayed everywhere in outlook (even in new mail or new appointment inspector).